# Grouping By column and sort by

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript, groupwise-maximum

suppose we have 2 tables

```
@Table
export class Parent extends Model {
 @PrimaryKey
 @HasMany(() => child, { as: 'child', foreignKey: 'PARENT_ID' })
 @Column
 ID: number
 @Column
 NAME: string
 ....
}

@Table
export class Child extends Model{
 @PrimaryKey
 @Column
 ID: number
 @Column
 NAME: string
 @PrimaryKey
 @BelongsTo(()=>Parent,{ as: 'parent', targetKey: 'ID', foreignKey: 'PARENT_ID' })
 @Column
 PARENT_ID: number
 @Column
 DOB: Date
.....
}
```

And this is the Table Data

```
 ___________  ______________________________________
| PARENTS   || CHILDRENS                            |
| ID NAME   ||  ID  NAME    PARENT_ID   DOB         |
| 1 David   ||  1   Oscar   1   2018-05-12 06:28:52 |
| 2 John    ||  2   Zac     2   2018-08-25 10:48:34 |
| 3 Steve   ||  3   Greg    1   2019-03-15 16:58:22 |
|           ||  4   Samuel  3   2019-12-16 23:12:34 |
|           ||  5   James   2   2020-03-25 08:48:52 |
|           ||  6   Dan     1   2021-01-05 16:48:12 |
|___________||  7   Kelly   3   2021-07-19 14:25:54 |
             |  8   Gary    1   2021-11-10 14:23:12 |
             |______________________________________|
```

and I expect the outcome result to be

```
 ___________________________________________________________________________________
| RESULT                                                                            |
| Parent_ID      Parent_Name         Child_ID        Child_Name      DOB            |
| 1                David                8               Gary    2021-11-10 14:23:12 |
| 3                Steve                7               Kelly   2021-07-19 14:25:54 |
| 2                John                 5               James   2020-03-25 08:48:52 |
|___________________________________________________________________________________|
```

I would prefer an answer in Sequelize but even raw query on SQL would be nice since I'm quite stuck with this.

this is just a small scale example but in reality there are tens of thousands parents and hundreds of thousands children so I also paginate the result. so performance should matter too :)

Comment: Why does the output have Gary instead of Dan?  Perhaps "last-born"?

Comment: @RickJames if you sort by DOB DESC you get the "last-born" but I only want one from each parent. so in other words each parent receives his last born kid

Comment: Sorting won't solve it -- that gives you 8 rows in the resultset, not the 3 you want.  See the tag I added.

Comment: What about twins?  Or will they necessarily have different birth times?

Comment: You can assume each dob is unique

Comment: OK, now I can recommend nnichols' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets a list of parents with the dob of their youngest child and then joins to children again -

```sql
WITH parents (id, name) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'David' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'John' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Steve'
), children (id, name, parent_id, dob) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'Oscar',  1, '2018-05-12 06:28:52' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Zac',    2, '2018-08-25 10:48:34' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Greg',   1, '2019-03-15 16:58:22' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'Samuel', 3, '2019-12-16 23:12:34' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'James',  2, '2020-03-25 08:48:52' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'Dan',    1, '2021-01-05 16:48:12' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'Kelly',  3, '2021-07-19 14:25:54' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'Gary',   1, '2021-11-10 14:23:12'
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT p.*, MAX(c.dob) youngest
    FROM parents p
    JOIN children c
        ON p.id = c.parent_id
    GROUP BY p.id
) y
JOIN children c
    ON y.id = c.parent_id
    AND y.youngest = c.dob
```

Comment: looking for a generic solution, as I said there can be many parents and even more children in the order of thousands

Comment: What's not generic about this?

Comment: you are giving all the data in the query and there can be many thousands as mentioned above, furthermore it doesn't look like my version of mysql support this query (doen't like the WITH)

Comment: No, they are CTEs used to mock your data! You just remove them.

Comment: My bad, your query does work! just needed to add order by c.dob on the end :D

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(c.dob),other fields from parents p
join childrens c
      on p.parentId = c.parentId
group by c.parentId
order by c.dob desc
```

try this.

Comment: no go, first it should b p.id = c.parentID but even after fixing that I receive (as per example)

Steve   - Samuel,
John  -  Zac,
David - Oscar

Answer (score 0):

Try running this query

```
SELECT  MAX(child.dob) AS dob, child.*, parent.*
    FROM  parents
    INNER JOIN  child  ON parent.ID = child.PARENT_ID
    GROUP BY  parent.ID
    ORDER BY  dob DESC;
```

Comment: That will fail the "only_full_group_by" test.

Comment: as @JohnMathew answer this gives for FIRST child born not the last